# How to set CODEOWNERS file to exclude specific users?

Tags: git, github

I have the following `repository/.github/CODEOWNERS` file:

```
* @company-name/team-name
```

Then when someone opens a PR, it automatically **random** chooses two team members as reviewers (on behalf of the team).

The problem is that the product owner and the designer are also in the team, and sometimes they got selected as reviewers.

How can I specify their usernames in the `CODEOWNERS` file so they can not get selected as reviewers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in the Team settings on github

[image: team settings]

Comment: Thank you! I don't have access to see this `Settings` tab in the team's page, but I've asked the tech-lead and it's done now :)